# How to customize Shipping Email Confirmation email template In Shopify Plus?

Tags: shopify

Hi i want to customize the design of shipping confirmation email in shopify.
Can you please tell me is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize all Shipping related emails in Shopify.

1. Click on Settings after you log into Shopify admin.
2. Click on notifications in the settings page.
3. You will find all the notifications and clicking any notification will show up the edit notification page.

[image: Shopify Shipping Notification]